# sencha archetict 3.5 publish not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

i created a project using sencha archetict 3.5 not it is not publishing the ext to the root directory saying no error at all 
First it was publishing my other project fine now its not working i don't know why please any help will be nice

sencha archetict 3.5
sencha cmd 
are all installed

Comment: Hi are you using publish button or build ? If you are using Cmd use build, it's different than publish button on the top in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was creating project in the same workspace so it wasn't able to publish the second app. 
i simply remove the `.sencha` directory from the project and than ran this command form the app folder in `cmd`

```
sencha app watch
```

and it create all the files needed for the app like **bootstrap.js** and .json files